# IF + AND + Date range formula

Tags: excel, date, if-statement

I have a problem to create a formula so I want to ask you for your help.

Excel sheet has 150 000 rows and with this formula I want to safe a time.

I have a Date, Name and Status and I need to see in other cell which Name was 4x or more time in consecutive GOOD or OK

Example of input:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/i82lz.jpg

I think IF + AND + DATE Range it’s enough, but I don’t know how to put it together.

Thanks a lot for your suggestions !

Here is what i have so far: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4j2ow.jpg

=COUNTIFS($D$2:$D$15;D2;$C$2:$C$15;"OK";$D$2:$D$15;D2;$E$2:$E$15;">="&E2;$E$2:$E$15;"<="&E2+7)+(COUNTIFS($D$2:$D$15;D2;$C$2:$C$15;"GOOD"))

With this i'm able to count how many times i have a Name, which is OK or GOOD and is in one week range, but i still don't know, what i have to change, that i will stop to count when false is there

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: some example and expected output would be nice to have

Comment: Use countif() or countifs() - you can count the number of times the name occurs or the same within a range of dates...

Comment: I'm rookie and i have just a basic knowledge and so far i just tried to do it without date. I don't except solution just suggestion. I want to put it together by myself after that.

Comment: @SolarMike so it will be countifs() with and() condition that the name has status 'OK' or 'GOOD' ??

Comment: If you try countifs() you may find you don't need an and()... But as you don't give a clear example of input & output I can only guess...

Comment: @SolarMike i edited my question, so i hope, that now it's clear, if not i will try again ;)

Comment: Is 4 the correct answer? I think there is confusion about how to interpret 'consecutive' - I think you want to count everything until the row with 'FALSE' in it for the same name?

Comment: @TomSharpe Yes 4 is correct answer, because i wanted to count OK and GOOD with same name in one week and you are right that is exactly what i need "count everything until the row with 'FALSE' in it for the same name" sorry i interpreted it badly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well here's something you could try. You could do it in one formula with an array formula, but with 150K rows it seems much better to try and avoid array formulas and use helper columns where necessary.

The first helper column just contains the person's ID if the row contains FALSE:

```
=IF(H2=FALSE,I2,"")
```

The second helper column contains the offset from the current row to the next FALSE for the same person:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(I2,K2:K$15,0)-1,16-ROW())
```

So now you can use basically your same COUNTIFS formula but replacing each range with an INDEX which specifies how many rows you should count:

```
=IF(H2=FALSE,0,COUNTIFS(I2:INDEX(I2:I$15,L2),I2,H2:INDEX(H2:H$15,L2),"GOOD",J2:INDEX(J2:J$15,L2),">="&J2,J2:INDEX(J2:J$15,L2),"<="&J2+7))+
    IF(H2=FALSE,0,COUNTIFS(I2:INDEX(I2:I$15,L2),I2,H2:INDEX(H2:H$15,L2),"OK",J2:INDEX(J2:J$15,L2),">="&J2,J2:INDEX(J2:J$15,L2),"<="&J2+7))
```

[image]

**Note 1**

The 16 in the second equation is to allow for the case where there are no more rows labelled FALSE after the current row, so the MATCH fails. This makes the Countifs count everything from the current rows to the end of the data.

**Note 2** - expanding to a larger range of data

You should be able replace the figure 16 with countA(I:I), the size of the data plus headers.

There shouldn't be a problem with using a larger range for the Index e.g.

```
    =IF(H2=FALSE,0,COUNTIFS(I2:INDEX(I2:I$150000,L2),I2,H2:INDEX(H2:H$150000,L2),"GOOD",J2:INDEX(J2:J$150000,L2),">="&J2,J2:INDEX(J2:J$150000,L2),"<="&J2+7))+
 IF(H2=FALSE,0,COUNTIFS(I2:INDEX(I2:I$150000,L2),I2,H2:INDEX(H2:H$150000,L2),"OK",J2:INDEX(J2:J$150000,L2),">="&J2,J2:INDEX(J2:J$150000,L2),"<="&J2+7))
```

but increasing the search range in the MATCH to 150K rows in the second formula does seriously affect performance when repeated 150K times. The only solution I can think of at the moment is to see if a maximum can be placed on the distance from any occurrence of a name to the next occurrence of the name with FALSE next to it.

Comment: Hi Tom please can i ask you what is the meaning of  number 16 here "16-ROW()"
 =IFERROR(MATCH(I2,K2:K$15,0)-1,16-ROW())

In case that i have for example 150k rows should i put there 150 000-ROW() ? And in case that i will add more data later should i still use this formula ? thanks

Comment: I will add a note to my answer.